# scrolling issue in safari, Ios browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, safari

I am making ajax call based on scroll event and getting some more data and displaying, that calls are working perfectly in all browsers except IE11, Safari, Ios and I found the reason why because by deafault "Smooth Scrolling" is enabled for IE11 but i don't know about "Safari", "Ios" browsers.
SO the ajax calls are calling frequently, so how to disable that setting using javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but if your problem is that scroll event is triggered to often, you should probably use debounce function. Simple implementation looks like this:

```
var scrollTimeout;

function onScrollHandler () {
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        // your ajax call
    }, 200);
}
```

or just use debounce function from some library like lodash.